# Parsing streams of json arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, stream

On the front-end I receive "chunked" data (json arrays) using "xhr" (onprogress)

When chunks arrive with a delay between them - everything is fine, this case is easy to handle - I just remember the response length and offset by that amount.

Problem arises when more than 1 "chunked" response arrive simultaneously making the end response unparsable, as it is incorrect json.

Structure:

```
[array 1][array 2] ... [array N]
```

Example: `[{"response": [{"itemId": 1}]}][{"response": [{"itemId": 2}]}]`

Question: is there a way to parse it?
I tried to use regular expressions - it worked fine up until the point when you have sub-arrays inside of the response bodies. In other words - it would fail for the abovementioned example.

It is going to match this:

```
1) {"response": [{"itemId": 1}
2) {"response": [{"itemId": 2}
```

The output (matches) I'm looking for:

```
1) {"response": [{"itemId": 1}]}
2) {"response": [{"itemId": 2}]}
```

This is the regular expression I'm using right now.

```
\[(.*?)\]/gi
```

Any ways to do it using regular expressions or do I need different approaches for that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "source" is where the chunks get available, you can:

```
var source = '[{"response": [{"itemId": 1}]}][{"response": [{"itemId": 2}]}]';
var chunks = JSON.parse('[' + source.replace(/\]\[/g, '\],\[') + ']');
for (var i in chunks) {
  // then work with chunks[i]...
}
```

Comment: This solution works very well! Simple and efficient. Thank you very much!